# Dartium in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dart, dartium

I'm working on a Dart/Polymer app using Chrome Dev Editor on Ubuntu 14.04.

I'd like to run in Dart (not JavaScript and dart.js) using Dartium, but I'm not sure how to actually *open* and use Dartium. I downloaded the zip from [dartlang.org](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download.html?utm_expid=51752263-1.WpTWnsvDTEGD1RYXp5u58g.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dartlang.org%2F). I just need to open the browser...

Is this something I can do *without* having to download the Dart Editor package and run Dartium from within that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start it from the command line.

Unzip the package.

cd chromium

./chrome

Comment: I downloaded a fresh copy and gave it another try. Within the unzipped package's directory, I'm getting this error:  

`./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Long shot - try running ./chrome-wrapper instead.

Comment: If that doesn't work libudev.so can be installed with "sudo apt-get install libudev-dev". After this there should be a symlink called /usr/lib/libudev.so.0. You may have some other missing dependencies though.

Comment: Alright, technically, `./chrome` *and* `./chrome-wrapper` worked, apparently.

The error came from an Ubuntu 14.04 problem that I had to research. I found a solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/how-do-i-resolve-a-cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-error). In the answer's comments, Phil Strong links the file, because it apparently is not available anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you have problems running Dartium, I found an answer here that helped me with this - just make sure that that the file locations are correct on your system.

The answer was to link the missing file together with an existing file:

**sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0**

Make sure you take a look at the [original post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330935/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libudev-so-0-brackets), but this solved it for me.

After this I ran Dartium with ./chrome on ubuntu 14.04